# If current field value(document library) equals to field value (list) . Update document library according to list field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, designer

(SharepointOnline and Sharepoint Designer Workflow).

Document library : **column A** and **column B** and **column EmailAdress**

List : **column C** and **column D** and **EmailAdressList**

So what i want to do is copy EmailAdressList(list) into EmailAdress(documentlibrary) **IF [column A = column C AND column B = Column D].**

The EmailAdressList value is set **by default** as photo that i circle in red.

Can you guys help me solve , if it possible answer with picture because i just use SPD around 1 month. im a newbie and i really want to learn. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call REST API in SharePoint Designer workflow to find the EmailAdressList from the list based on "column A = column C AND column B = Column D".

Here are steps

1. [Grant full control permission to a workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo).
2. Create a workflow for the doc library in SharePoint Designer.
3. Trigger the workflow when item is created and modified.
4. In the workflow, add a app steps.
5. Build directory and add the Accept and the Content-Type headers.

   Create a workflow variable with directory type named 'JSonRequestHeader'. Output the variable dictionnary as JSonRequestHeader.

   [image]
6. Call web service

   `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Email Adresses List')/items?$filter=(column_x0020_C eq '[%Current Item:column A%]') and (column_x0020_D eq '[%Current Item:column B%]')​`

   (Note: In my test, the list name is "Email Adresses List". "column_x0020_C" and "column_x0020_D" are the internal names of "column C" and "column D". [How to check the internal name of a column](http://mstechtalk.com/check-column-internal-name-sharepoint-list/))

   [image]
7. Associate the JSonRequestHeader variable to RequestHeaders.

   [image]
8. In the Call action, click on response and associate the response to a new variable : JSonResult (of type Dictionnary).
9. After the Call action add a new Get action.

   Get `d/results(0)/EmailAdressList` from JSonResult.
10. Set current item EmailAdress to this output value.

The Workflow summary:

[image]

How to call REST API in designer workflow:

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Trigger the workflow manually for the existing items in doc library.

Comment: hi thanks for help! based on your last sentence and before i do this, may i know if this workflow applicable when a new item is added? or it only works when we trigger it manually.

Comment: check my step 3. If you enable that, the workflow will be triggered automatically when an item is create/modified. For the already-created item, you need to start the workflow manually or edit it properties to trigger the workflow.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Hazrin, if the suggestion helps you, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case.